# How do I use Invoke-Command to run a bath file as a remote server?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I just wrote a batch file that I would like run as a remote server but it keeps giving me errors in PowerShell when I use `Invoke-Command`. The batch file runs fine. Does anybody have idea what am missing out on? Below is my PowerShell script and the error I get.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "HEPWIN2020-10" -Scriptblock {Start-Process C:\DHCP\batfile1.bat}
```

The error I get is:

```
Invoke-Command : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument ''.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-Command -ComputerName "HEPWIN2012-03" -Scriptblock{Start-Proce ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
```

Comment: Add a space between `-Scriptblock` and the actual script block `{...}`

Comment: @Theo It still give the same error even with the space

Comment: Which Powershell Version are you using? Your Tags dispay both PSv2 and v3..

Comment: Then please edit your question with the space added. Also, I think you'd better quote the FilePath `C:\DHCP\batfile1.bat` because I assume this is just an example file and the real one may contain space characters.

Answer (score -1):

FYI , If the remote computer has credentials you should pass that too. And instead of `Start-Process` use the `Invoke-Expression`. The below should work.

```
$Username = 'USER'
$Password = 'PASSWORD'
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$pass
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "Server1" -credential $cred -ErrorAction Stop -ScriptBlock {Invoke-Expression -Command:"cmd.exe /c 'C:\DHCP\batfile1.bat'"}
```

Comment: [Do **NOT** use `Invoke-Expression`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/).